# Как совместить два кода в один?

Tags: visual-basic

Как совместить эти два скрипта, чтобы при вводе (к примеру) "хочу литр водки"

```
Input ""; a
if a = "хочу литр водки" then print "пожалуйста"
end
```

Но я хочу, чтобы вместо Print "пожалуйста" исполнялась api

```
Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (
    ByVal hwnd As Long, 
    ByVal lpOperation As String, 
    ByVal lpFile As String, 
    ByVal lpParameters As String, 
    ByVal lpDirectory As String, 
    ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

Private Sub Form_Load()
Call ShellExecute(0&, vbNullString, "c:\mydoc\пожалуйста.doc", vbNullString, vbNullString, vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Я просто хочу сделать так, чтобы было поле для ввода слова (в моем случае это литр водки) и чтобы при вводе "литр водки" он исполнял файл "d:mydoclitr_vodki.doc".

Answer (score 1):

На знание васика не претендую.

```
Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (
    ByVal hwnd As Long, 
    ByVal lpOperation As String, 
    ByVal lpFile As String, 
    ByVal lpParameters As String, 
    ByVal lpDirectory As String, 
    ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

Private Sub Form_Load()
Call ShellExecute(0&, vbNullString, "c:\mydoc\litr_vodki.doc", vbNullString, vbNullString, vbNormalFocus)
End Sub

где-то в далекой галактике....

Input ""; a
if a = "хочу литр водки" then Form_Load()
end
```